# Orders of Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

Let H be a normal subgroup of G and for any $g \in G$ that $|g|=n$ and $|G/H|=m$. Suppose the $gcd(n,m)=p$ where $p$ is prime. Show that for any $ a\in gH$, then $a^p\in H$.

Could I get some help on this? I know that the order of $|gH|$ divides both $|G/H|$ and $|g|$.

Comment: Well since you know that the order of $gH$ divides both $|G/H|$ and $|g|$, it must also divide their gcd, which we are told is $p$. In other words, $(gH)^p$ must be the identity element of $H$ - but $a \in gH$ is equivalent to $gH=aH$, so $(gH)^p = (aH)^p = a^pH$. The fact that $p$ is prime seems to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Bezout's Lemma guarantees the existence of integers $x$ and $y$ with $xn+ym=p$. Hence $a^{p}=(a^y)^m$.